# Ifstream open() doesn't set error bits when argument is a directory

Tags: c++, ifstream

In a C++ program, using std::ifstream, I'm attempting to open a user-specified file -- so far so good. However, I accidentally entered a filename that's actually a directory, and I was quite surprised to see that attempting to open() that directory didn't generate any errors.

Here's a minimal example:

```
std::ifstream f;
f.open("..");
if(!f.is_open() || !f.good() || f.bad() || f.fail()) {
    std::cout << "error bit set on open" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

No sign of error here. If I go on and attempt to getline(), getline() sets an error bit all right.

```
std::string str;
getline(f, str);

if(f.eof()) std::cout << "getline set eofbit" << std::endl;
else if(f.bad()) std::cout << "getline set badbit" << std::endl;
else if(f.fail()) std::cout << "getline set failbit" << std::endl;
```

This outputs "getline set badbit", which is reasonable. Using the >> operator throws an underflow exception, which is also okay.

Now, my question is, how could I detect that the user entered a directory name instead of a proper filename? Is there any way to do that? Getting and ungetting bytes from the stream seem tedious and error-prone.

Also, why is this so? I realize that it's all just the same data from the point of view of the program, but I'd assume the OS would also send some "hey, this is a directory" kind of message.

Comment: On what platform are you getting this behaviour?

Comment: C++ has no notion of "directory". You need some platform-specific library (like Posix or Windows).

Comment: Oh, Ubuntu 10.04, compiler is gcc 4.4.3.

Comment: @KerrekSB : ...or a portable library like Boost or Qt.

Comment: There may be platforms where opening a directory and reading from it is a perfectly valid thing to do. If you're on a Unix-like platform, you can use fstat to figure out what type of file it is. Windows will have some way of doing it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what your system is, so it's hard to say, but generally,
`filebuf::open` will only return an error if your system level open
fails.  And I've worked on Unix systems where you could `open()` a
directory; I've even worked on some where you could read it after the
open (at least if it was a locally mounted filesystem).

As to what to do about it: about all I can think of is to try to `get`
the first character, then put it back.  But this fails if the file is
empty, so it's not really a solution either.  At the system level (and
from a QoI point of view, I'd expect `filebuf::open` to do this if the
system did allow opening a directory), you can use a system level call
(`stat` in Unix) to determine whether the file is a directory or not.
(There's a race condition, of course: between the moment you detect that
it's a normal file, and the moment you do the open, another process
could delete the file and create a directory.  It's probably not a
frequent occurance, however.)

Comment: Oh, so it IS platform-specific, after all, I could have guessed. Thanks for the explanation. Yes, this is on Linux (Ubuntu, same happens on Debian, unsurprisingly). Since I'm just trying to ensure that it's a valid and readable filestream from which I can read stuff, getting and ungetting is reasonable, though I hoped for a cleaner solution. Dependencies and system calls seem like overkill. I mean, I can live with the error, but, um, it just looked strange.

Comment: @SáT: I would also guess it is specific to the underlying file system used on the hardware (note: some OS allow you to choose the filesystem used on disks).

Comment: @LokiAstari I think so.  IIRC (it has been some time since I tried it), under Solaris, `open` on a directory worked on locally mounted disks (UFS), but not if the filesystem was NFS.

Comment: Suggest to reedit: "I've even worked on somewhere you could read from it(i.e. the opened folder) after the open (at least if it was a locally mounted filesystem)."