# use boost to return file in a directory

Tags: c++, file, boost, directory, filesystems

I have a directory that should contain one file. it has an extension of .png but the name is semi-random. I've tried a dozen tutorials for using boost to get the filename but they all exit the console with no error. what is the simplest function to use boost to get this file name?

Comment: _'I've tried a dozen tutorials for using boost to get the filename'_ Could you be a bit more specific, may be on one of your trials' problems. As it is it's pretty unclear what you're asking for?!? There's [`boost::file::exists()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268023/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform), if it's what you're after.

Comment: im asking that for a path. lets say  fs::path mypath = "C:\\test\\"; return the name of the only file in that directory

Comment: `boost::path` and [wildcard search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257721/can-i-use-a-mask-to-iterate-files-in-a-directory-with-boost)? I'm afraid from this reference it's not possible like that. But you could of course use regex to parse for any listed filenames from a path.

Comment: doesnt work. boost:filesystem:directory_entry has no member leaf

Comment: If your directory contains only one file, can't you produce a list of all files in that directory. Then the only file that is there must be the one you want.

Comment: of course, but how do i get that only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the file/directory names placed n a particular `boost::path` instance you have, use boosts [`directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration), as shown in the linked example.

To check for particular file-/directory name signatures found from iterating, [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) might come in handy.

Comment: error identifier is_directory is undefined. directory_iterator is undefined same for is_regular, file_size and exists

Comment: Are you sure to have the referenced boost version installed and made up all `-I`, `-L`, `-l<lib>` options setup correctly? Not to mention namespace references? **EDIT:** Sorry, I gave the wrong link for `directory_iterator`, check again ...

Comment: @Aaron I've updated the link, check the example there please!