# Why would I need stat to check if a directory already exists?

Tags: c, mkdir

From my homework:

> Backup files are stored in a hidden directory called .mybackup, which
>   your program creates, if necessary. To create a directory, use the
>   mkdir() function (click here for details), but be sure to check
>   whether the directory already exists (using stat() or checking for
>   EEXIST). If the directory already exists, do not overwrite it.

I thought mkdir inherently returns -1 if the directory already exists. I definitely read that somewhere. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: I'd suggest checking [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314042/stat-vs-mkdir-with-eexist) as well: it's not a duplicate, but very close to it. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mkdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir) returns -1 for any error. So to distinguish between errors, that is, to discover if the directory already exists, you should either use the `stat` function or check `errno` for `EEXIST` after `mkdir` returns -1.

```
if(mkdir(".mybackup", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH) == -1)
{
    if(errno == EEXIST)
    {
        // Directory already exists, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to include <sys/stat.h> (for `mkdir`) and <errno.h> (to handle `errno` and `EEXIST`).

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir` function can fail for many reasons:

> [EACCES]
>   Search permission is denied on a component of the path prefix, or write permission is denied on the parent directory of the directory to be created.
>
> [EEXIST]
>   The named file exists.
>
> [ELOOP]
>   A loop exists in symbolic links encountered during resolution of the path argument.
>
> [EMLINK]
>   The link count of the parent directory would exceed {LINK_MAX}.
>
> [ENAMETOOLONG]
>   The length of the path argument exceeds {PATH_MAX} or a pathname component is longer than {NAME_MAX}.
>
> [ENOENT]
>   A component of the path prefix specified by path does not name an existing directory or path is an empty string.
>
> [ENOSPC]
>   The file system does not contain enough space to hold the contents of the new directory or to extend the parent directory of the new directory.
>
> [ENOTDIR]
>   A component of the path prefix is not a directory.
>
> [EROFS]
>   The parent directory resides on a read-only file system.
>   The mkdir() function may fail if:
>
> [ELOOP]
>   More than {SYMLOOP_MAX} symbolic links were encountered during resolution of the path argument.
>
> [ENAMETOOLONG]
>   As a result of encountering a symbolic link in resolution of the path argument, the length of the substituted pathname string exceeded {PATH_MAX}.

If the function returns `-1` you can't be sure of which specific error without checking `errno`, that's why it is suggested.

Comment: +1 for EMLINK, typical user is unlikely to hit this limit on any modern file systems, but these do happen in the field!