# Race condition with stat and mkdir in sequence

Tags: mkdir, stat, coverity

Coverity complains of . toctou: Calling function mkdir that uses DIR after a check function. This can cause a time-of-check, time-of-use race condition

```
if (stat(DIR, &st) != 0)
{
    if (mkdir(DIR, 0755) < 0)
    {
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

Is it good enough to change the code to ,I was using stat only for file exist check

```
if (mkdir(NDUID_DIR, 0755) < 0)
{
    if(errno != EEXIST)
    {
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your snippets appear to be incorrect and/or incomplete.

On OpenBSD, [`sys_mkdir`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/kern/vfs_syscalls.c#sys_mkdir) would `return` `-1`, and set `errno` to [`EEXIST`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/sys/errno.h#EEXIST) when the target file is present.  However, that doesn't guarantee that the target file is a directory -- an existing regular file would still result in [`mkdir(2)`](http://mdoc.su/-/mkdir.2) returning the exact same `EEXIST`.

For guidance of the widely accepted approach, take a look at how [`mkdir(1)` `-p` option](http://mdoc.su/-/mkdir.1) is implemented across the BSDs ([`bin/mkdir/mkdir.c#mkpath` in OpenBSD](http://bxr.su/o/bin/mkdir/mkdir.c#mkpath) and [NetBSD](http://bxr.su/n/bin/mkdir/mkdir.c#mkpath)), all of which, on [`mkdir(2)`'s](http://mdoc.su/-/mkdir.2) error, appear to immediately call [`stat(2)`](http://mdoc.su/-/stat.2) to subsequently run the [`S_ISDIR`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/sys/stat.h#S_ISDIR) macro to ensure that the existing file is a directory, and not just any other type of a file.