# Adding a file close statement causes a seg fault

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

When trying to close the file after reading it, I get a seg fault on running the program.

```
    int inputDirectory()
    {
    char fileName[64];char directoryBuffer[256];FILE *fp;
    printf("\n> Please type the filename containing the list of directories. >");
    inputFix(fileName, sizeof(fileName));
    fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    if(access(fileName, F_OK) == 0)
    {
        if (fp == 0)
        {
            printf("> Error opening file.");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (access(fileName, R_OK) == 0)
            {
                while (fgets(directoryBuffer, sizeof(directoryBuffer), (FILE*)fp))
                {       
                    readCheck(directoryBuffer);
                    printf("%s \n", directoryBuffer);
                    getInode(directoryBuffer);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n> File can't be read.");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n> File %s does not exist ", fileName); 
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void inputFix(char string[],int length)
{
int ch, len = 0;
fgets(string, length, stdin);
string[strcspn(string, "\r\n")] = '\0';
len = strlen(string);
if (len == length - 1)
{
     while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}
}

void readCheck(char string[])
{
    string[strcspn(string, "\r\n")] = '\0';
}
```

Ive been reading into race conditions, but from my understanding there isn't one? Is there a need to check to see if the file exists before trying to open it? Is there a need to include some of the checks that I'm using?

Comment: "Ive been reading into race conditions" ... what lead you down that path? Is this part of a thread-proc or invoked somewhere on a free-threaded COM server or some-such?

Comment: Was reading into possible seg faults from File I/O. It didn't make much sense.

Comment: I think it has to do with that if the file doesn't exist, it skips over and then fclose(fp) is called, where no file is opened. hence the 0x0 point of fp when an invalid file name is given.

Comment: Appears fclose(fp) needs to be after the while loop.

Comment: So ... this makes me wonder: `(FILE*)fp` ? That thing is *not* already a `FILE*` ??

Comment: And *what* while-loop? There is **no** `fclose()` in the only while-loop of the  code posted. That `fclose()` should be immediately after the `else { printf("\n> File can't be read."); }` block. There is nowhere else in this code where it makes sense to have it (and even there, it is wrong, as you should be checking access *prior* to opening the file, or testing `fp` prior to `fclose()`-ing it). Why are you invoking `access` after `fopen()`, but *before* you test the success of the `fopen()` anyway?

Comment: I fixed it placing a fclose() after the while loop. The code has been edited as I saw that the fopen() should be after the access call.

Comment: If you open a file successfully for reading, there's no need to use `access()` too.  The `access()` function is interesting.  It is designed primarily for use by SUID programs to see whether the real UID (rather than the effective UID normally used for checking permissions) can access the file.  In a non-SUID program, it works fine, but you're better off trying the open and spotting failure (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission: EAFP) than risking a TOCTOU (Time of Check, Time of Use) failure (Look Before You Leap: LBYL). See [SO 404795](http://stackoverflow.com/q/404795/).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at these lines.

```
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        printf("> Error opening file.");
        fclose(fp);   // NOT NEEDED. REMOVE THE LINE
    }
```

It seems you don't need to call `fclose` when you were not able to open the file.

Remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

If `fp` is null (equal to 0), you do not need to close it, the file was never opened to begin with. You should close `fp` after you are done successfully reading from it.

Comment: I've made the change to place it at the end. It still appears to seg fault.

Comment: What line? If you don't know how to fix a segfault, I suggest you [do some research](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html)

Comment: Running it through gdb tells me its caused by fclose(fp) even after moving it. Even if it doesn't read from the file, I've opened it before going through the checks.

Comment: And what is the value of `fp` according to gdb?

Comment: 0xb7e852f2, which is weird because the program starts at 0x80486a0. 0xb7e852f2 would be a library reference right? I've used -ggdb but gdb doesn't see the debugging symbols.

Comment: `-g` is the flag to compile with debug info. Use `print` to print a variable.

Comment: I've placed a breakpoint before the final fclose(fp). FP is the value of 0xb7fffad0. which holds another address 0xb7fffa74, which points to 0xb7fdcb18, which points to 0xb7fff918 = NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the file at the end regardless of whether the file ever opened or not. Calling fclose on an unopened file can cause a crash. Try this instead. I have moved the fclose statement to be called only when fp is not NULL.

```
  int inputDirectory()
    {
    char fileName[64];char directoryBuffer[256];FILE *fp;
    printf("\n> Please type the filename containing the list of directories. >");
    inputFix(fileName, sizeof(fileName));
    if(access(fileName, F_OK) == 0)
    {
        fp = fopen(fileName,"r");

        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("> Error opening file.");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (access(fileName, R_OK) == 0)
            {
                while (fgets(directoryBuffer, sizeof(directoryBuffer), (FILE*)fp))
                {       
                    readCheck(directoryBuffer);
                    printf("%s \n", directoryBuffer);
                    getInode(directoryBuffer);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n> File can't be read.");
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n> File %s does not exist ", fileName); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only call [`fclose()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html) on a `FILE*` which had been returned by a successful call to [`fopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

To test wether `fopen()` had been successful compare its result against `NULL`. If this test succeeds the call had **not** been successful:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char filename[] = "myfile";
  FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (NULL == fp)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "fopen(\"%s\", ...) failed.\n", filename);
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "fopen(\"%s\", ...) succeeded.\n", filename);

    /* Perform operation on fp here. */

    fclose(fp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```