# EAFP. Ask for forgiveness not permission in Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Is it a good practice in Java to ask for forgiveness not permission in general and in the next example?

The example is:

```
try {
    Cell value = array2D[rowIndex][columnIndex];
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
```

As you can see in the above piece of code we get `value` out of the `array2D`. If the `value` is out of bounds we do nothing.

I ask this question because it is much easier to implement `EAFP` than `LBYL` (look before you leap) in some cases (for example finding all neighbors of given `Cell` in `array2D`).

Comment: I'm guessing you've come from a python background. I'm only new to java but I'm finding that the presence of scopes in java somewhat hobbles your capability to make good use of EAFP. See in your example above `Cell` is out of scope before you can use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LBYL vs EAFP in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404795/lbyl-vs-eafp-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the overhead of throwing an exception by checking the size of the array:

```
if(rowIndex < array2D.length)
{
    if(columnIndex < array2D[rowIndex].length)
    {
        // you are safe here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not a good idea from several reasons:

- The run time performance of an `if` is much better than of a `try`...`catch`
- The code is less readable when combining a lot of unnecessary `catch`es

Comment: Is there any cases when we prefer to use EAFP in Java? Or exceptions are for exceptional cases only as @Elliott said.

Comment: This actually answers the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I personally think it's a terrible practice to use try catch instead of getting the array lengths; `Exception`(s) are for exceptional circumstances and the length of an array is a field

```
if (rowIndex < array2D.length && columnIndex < array2D[rowIndex].length) {
  Cell value = array2D[rowIndex][columnIndex];
  // ...
} else {
  break;
}
```