# How to check if a file is in read-only mode in C

Tags: c, file, unix, readonly, chmod

How I can check if a file is in read-only mode in C? I would like to check if it is possible write in a file before opening it.

Comment: Have a look at the `stat()` function

Comment: I find it odd that you accept a solution which, despite being suggesting something wise and correct, does not really answer to your question which states **before opening it**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fopen, and check for the return value. Check here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where it is easiest and most reliable to try opening the file for writing, and react appropriately if the open fails ('Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than for Permission') than to try and determine whether it will fail first ('Look Before You Leap') — see [LBYL vs EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404795/lbyl-vs-eafp-in-java/405220#405220).

You can use [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html), but it is modestly tricky to determine the permissions correctly.  Also, there could be ACLs that mean you can access the file for writing even if the permissions reported by `stat()` indicate that you can't (or vice versa).  You could use [`access(filename, W_OK)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html), and it will usually give you the correct answer — unless your program is running with effective UID different from real UID.

However, any LBYL strategy also suffers from TOCTOU — Time of Check, Time of Use — issues.  The permissions on the file, or one of the directories leading to it, might change between the time when you check the file permissions and the time when you actually try to open the file.  The permissions might have said "it is OK" but the file could have been removed, or changed to read-only since then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fstat() function.
See man 2 fstat for details:
http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat

Comment: Note that you can only use the [`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) function on an open file descriptor.  The function to work with a file name is [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) or one of the other functions — `lstat()` or `fstatat()` — listed on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

While retrieving the file permissions with the `fstat`/`stat` functions will give you good hints is the usual cases, I would recommend not to trust them too much as there are corner ones where the file will be writable despite being reported read only, for example if you are root, and also cases you won't be able to write the file despite being reported writeable, for example if it is located on a read-only file system.

ACLs might also play a similarly confusing role by reversing what the st_mode is reporting.