# "Style" attribute not getting identified in Selenium Webdriver for the mentioned case

Tags: selenium, styles, webdriver, getattribute

For the following html code in https://www.parcelhero.com/en-gb/courier-services/carriers/dhl, getattribute("style") fetches null value. Why?

```
<div class="dvPageShare" style="position: relative; top: -50px;">
```

Following is the Code used:

```
driver.get("https://www.parcelhero.com/en-gb/courier-services/carriers/dhl");
    List <WebElement>SocialLink = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
        for (WebElement social : SocialLink)
 {
if( social.getAttribute("class")!=null && social.getAttribute("class").equals("dvPageShare"))
                {
System.out.println("Present");System.out.println(social.getAttribute("style"));
}

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404795/lbyl-vs-eafp-in-java) approach. *Find the element by class name* and handle exceptions:

```
try {
    WebElement social = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dvPageShare"));
    System.out.println("Present");
    System.out.println(social.getAttribute("style"));
} catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
    System.out.println("Not Present");
}
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git-history/master/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) `findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.`

Answer (score 1):

alecxe is using the right approach, I would just code it slightly differently. If there are no elements that match, code execution falls through the loop. You can specifically check for `socialLinks.size() > 0`, if you want... maybe log a message in that case. You'll have to decide what is best in your case.

```
List<WebElement> socialLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.dvPageShare"));
for (WebElement socialLink : socialLinks)
{
    System.out.println("Present");
    System.out.println(socialLink.getAttribute("style"));
}
```

This CSS Selector `div.dvPageShare` means find a `DIV` that has the class (.) dvPageShare.

I didn't try running your code but I did see that there are two `DIV`s with `class = "dvPageShare"` on that page, one of which did not have a style attribute. Maybe that's where the `null` is coming from?

[CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors). Learn them... they are very powerful and every automator should understand and use them.

Comment: In order to reduce the response time I was using HtmlUnitDriver class which was working for all the classes other than "dvPageShare". It was able to identify this Class but not the "Style" attribute of this Class. Hence I was getting null.for Style.

Comment: hmm.. I don't have any experience using HtmlUnitDriver so I don't know what the issue might be. If you haven't already, you might try googling HtmlUnitDriver and css style... maybe others have had a similar issue with nulls. Sorry I couldn't help more.