# Occasional IOError writing to file

Tags: python, io

I am running the following code very often to write to files from Python using the following:

```
def function():
    file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../../my_file')
    fifo = open(file, 'w')
    if (os.path.isfile(file) and os.access(file, os.W_OK)):
        fifo.write("stuff")
        fifo.close()
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        function()
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error (not all the time):

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is self-explanatory, but I do not understand then why all the precautions do not work, like `isfile` or `access..W_OK` ? How do I avoid having this issue?

Also, the slower the machine, the less often the error is encountered.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Note that you open the file before checking for access.

Comment: @Koterpillar the error occurs at `fifo.write("stuff")`

Comment: Are there other processes that might delete the file or move the directories around?

Comment: @Koterpillar there is another process that deletes the file, but only after reading it

Comment: Not really an answer to the original question, but try writing to another file and renaming it to `my_file` when you're done. Renaming is atomic and won't cause race conditions.

Comment: your check and write are not atomic so it's only normal to fail sometimes if you have another process that deletes that file

Comment: You both make sense.. havent thought of that classical issue

Comment: why do you not use with block and exceptions instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also "[LBYL vs EAFP in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404795/lbyl-vs-eafp-in-java)":

Instead of checking if the action is ok (LBYL), you should do an EAFP approach. Just do what you want to do and check if it has worked correctly.

Besides, better don't call `function()` recursively, it might lead to a stack overflow if the error persists.

Better do

```
def function():
    file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../../my_file')
    while True:
        try:
            with open(file, 'w') as file: # automatically closes...
                file.write("some stuff")
        except IOError, e:
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        break # the while loop
```

Comment: your solution suits me best as it requires minimal changes to the existing code. Thank you