# what is the elegant way to check if a nested list has and has NOT a value at a specific index?

Tags: python, list, exception, nested-lists

lets say we have 2d array:

```
ar = [[1,2],
      [3,4]]

if ar[1][1]:
#works
if not ar[3][4]: 
#breaks!!
```

since I am new to python, need to know what is the elegant syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's much loved *EAFP* approach with exception handling would be my way of doing it.

```
try:
    print(ar[i][j])  # i -> row index, j -> col index
except IndexError:
    print('Error!')
```

Another way, also known as the *LYBL* approach, would be using `if` checks:

```
if i < len(ar) and j < len(ar[i]):
    print(ar[i][j])
```

And here's the "one liner" version (that kills readability, but you seem to want):

```
print(ar[i][j] if i < len(ar) and j < len(ar[i]) else "Error")
```

---

- [What is the EAFP principle in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)
- [LBYL vs EAFP in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404795/lbyl-vs-eafp-in-java) (the same concept applies to almost any language.)

Comment: [Explanation of EAFP and LYBL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).

Comment: that should be done in one line :( I was expecting python could show me some power.

Comment: @DragonKnight Your one liner: `print(ar[i][j] if i < len(ar) and j < len(ar[i]) else "Error")` I don't recommend it, it kills readability.

Comment: thats true, its not readable. i wished `if not ar[3][4]: ` would work elegantly. thanks yall.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a check you need to do often, you could make yourself a little helper function so your main code flows better:

```
def has_item_at(items, i, j):
    return i < len(items) and j < len(items[i])

def main():
    items = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    if has_item_at(items, 1, 1):
        # do stuff
    if has_item_at(items, 3, 4):
        # don't do stuff
```

If you need to check for existence and also retrieve the item, you could do something like this instead:

```
def get_item(items, i, j, default=None):
    if i < len(items) and j < len(items[i]):
        return items[i][j]
    return default

def main():
    items = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    item = get_item(items, 1, 1)
    if item is not None:
        # do stuff
```