# Qt Customwidget appearance not changing after setting stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I want to provide a system to write own Styesheets for my Application. I load the stylesheets like this:
I use QFileInfo to check if  the file exists (like in this article [How to check whether file exists in Qt in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273816/how-to-check-whether-file-exists-in-qt-in-c]))

```
bool Settings::fileExists(const QString &path)
{
    QFileInfo check_file(path);
    if (check_file.exists() && check_file.isFile()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I open the file

```
QString filePath = stylesPath + "/"  + text;
    if(fileExists(filePath)) {
        QFile stylesheetFile(filePath);
        stylesheetFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
        QString newStylesheet = QLatin1String(stylesheetFile.readAll());
        stylesheetFile.close();
        if(m_previewFrame) {
            m_previewFrame->setStyleSheet(newStylesheet);
            m_previewFrame->style()->unpolish(m_previewFrame);
            m_previewFrame->style()->polish(m_previewFrame);
            m_previewFrame->update();
        }
    }
    qDebug()  << m_previewFrame->styleSheet();
}
```

Edit3: The m_previewframe is a Qframe object and I want to change the style of a customWidget which is a children of m_previewFrame. Do i have to polish/unpolish for every children instead for only the QFrame?

The stylesheet is for a custom widget, so have overriden the paintEvent like in this article [Qt Stylesheet for custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276330/qt-stylesheet-for-custom-widget])
Edit:It is important to use QFile::Text ([Unable to set stylesheet properties using qss file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278464/unable-to-set-stylesheet-properties-using-qss-file?rq=1))

If I run this it prints out the content of the file like this

```sh
"CustomWidget{\n\tbackground-color:black;\n}"
```

but it only reloads the style once.
If I try to pass a QString directly like this:

```
auto newStyleSheet = QString("CustomWidget{background-color:black;}");
m_previewFrame->setStyleSheet(newStylesheet);
m_previewFrame->style()->unpolish(m_previewFrame);
m_previewFrame->style()->polish(m_previewFrame);
m_previewFrame->update();
```

and it works.
Edit: the first example works too. But it just works once. If I have set a stylesheet once it won't update the other stylesheet.

Edit2: It definitely is an update problem neither polish/unpolish + update() nor ensurePolished() + update() works. 
I am not sure how i can force my QFrame and its children to rerender.
Qt unpolish:

> Note that unpolish() will only be called if the widget is destroyed. This can cause problems in some cases, e.g, if you remove a widget from the UI, cache it, and then reinsert it after the style has changed; some of Qt's classes cache their widgets.

This means i have to destroy the object?

I am using C++17 , Qt Creator 4.9.2 and Desktop Qt 5.13.0 MinGW 64 Bit

Comment: What is the output of "qDebug()  << m_previewFrame->styleSheet();" when you set the style like in the working second example? The way you load the file seems right, i do it basicly the same and it works for me. This looks to me like \r\n\ could be the issue.

Comment: The Output is similar to the string. If i use QString::simplified I get the exact same string and get rid of the \r\n but somehow it doesn't work. I also noticed, that the second example just works if I don't have a stylesheet in my MainWindow loaded where I change my CustomWidget.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this helps, but overriding QEvent::Paint for custom widgets is not needed in order to be able to apply style sheets to them. It might even be causing problems for you, since only QStyle::PE_Widget element is requested to be drawn while many more other elements can be drawn by Qt for you. Also, QWidget::setStyleSheet() should unpolish and polish everything automatically for you, thus no repolishing should be required. In other words, only the following lines should be required for you:

```
auto newStyleSheet = QString("CustomWidget{background-color:black;}");
m_previewFrame->setStyleSheet(newStylesheet);
```

I am not sure if it would work, but as I have tried (by setting it through a QTextEdit), it works without any problems as many times as you set stylesheet. In any case, the problem should be somewhere else. By the way, I am using C++11, Qt Creator 4.8.2, and Qt5.9.8. Maybe newer Qt version has such type of a bug? I doubt very much that C++17 or Qt Creator 4.9.2 would cause any issues.

Comment: I solved my Problm by calling polish/unpolish + update for every children of the previewFrame (recursive) and overriding paintEvent for every CustomWidget (calling parents paintEvent if it is not a Widget). But this caused problems with setStylesheet. Sometimes it works and sometimes it gives the warning could not parse Stylesheet of object QFrame(0x18e6130, name="previewframe") and the stylesheet doesnt change. I tried not to override paintEvent and / or not using polish/unpolish but it is not working.