# Fopen a file in C

Tags: c

This is my code :

```
outfile = fopen(outname, "w");//outname="/home/user/dir/file"
if (!outfile) {
printf("There was a problem opening %s for writing\n", outname);
}
else {
 /* write to the file, */
 }
```

at run it display: There was a problem opening /home/user/dir/file for writing
Please i ask if you have an idea about this error
Thank you.

Comment: Does the file exist? Does it have write permissions?

Comment: ...and does the path exist? i.e. all directories user dir etc. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`perror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html) for a better description of the error.

```
if (!outfile) {
    /* printf("There was a problem opening %s for writing\n", outname); */
    perror(outname);
}
```

Comment: i have this message fopen: No such file or directory, please how can verify if a directory exist on Linux (with C)?

Comment: Use access, see eg [this SO question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform).