# 'fopen' returning NULL file pointer, even if the files is created using C

Tags: c, fopen, null-pointer

I am using the following code to open a file in write mode:

```
FILE *pf = fopen("c:\\test.txt", "w");
if (NULL == pf)
{
    printf("File pointer is NULL");
}
```

Sometime the file is created, and I get file pointer properly, but sometime I get the log "File pointer is NULL" even if the file is created on the C drive. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try printing `strerror(errno)`, which might give a hint as to why `fopen` failed.

Comment: you must `fclose() ` after using file.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? It's a little unusual to be creating a file in the root directory of a drive. Usually you'd want to do it in your own user folder somewhere to ensure proper permissions.

Comment: You need admin privileges to write to C:\.  Are you running as an admin user?

Comment: I this this is helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx:

> A null pointer value indicates an error.

In modern windows creating file on the root of drive C requires administrative privileges.

Can you reproduce the same behaviour in safe location, for example in temp directory returned by **GetTempPath** function?

> If an error occurs, the global variable **errno** is set and may be used
>   to get specific error information.

Check the 'errno' value. It should contain something like **EACCES** or **EPERM**.

You say:

> ...even if file is created in c drive.

I would guess that this file remains from one of previous successful runs under admin. Check the creation timestamp.

Comment: Wow. I appreciate your sense of humor of pointing to the POSIX function manual on MSDN.

Comment: Andrejs, original question is Windows-specific.

Comment: Can't see anything Windows specific here so far.

Comment: I'm getting errno as '0' but even after that the file pointer is NULL & I verified the timestamp of the file, it is getting created after each run. still facing the same issue & FYI this problem is coming on windows system

Comment: Hmm, on my machine (Win7) errno is EACCES when i try creating file in c:\\:
FILE *pf = fopen("c:\\test.txt","w");
if(NULL == pf)
{

printf("File pointer is NULL %d %s\n", errno, errno==EACCES?"EACCES":"");
}

output:
File pointer is NULL 13 EACCES