# How to open a file with append mode only if it exist

Tags: c++, c, fopen

The function `fopen("file-name",a);` will return a pointer to the end of the file. If the file exist it is opened, otherwise a new file is created.
Is it possible to use the append mode and open the file only if it already exist? (and return a NULL pointer otherwise).

Thanks in advance

Comment: In C you can [check if a file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform) before opening it.

Comment: It does not return a pointer to the end of the file - it returns a FILE pointer with the current write location at the end of the current content. You can check if the file already had some content by checking if the "current" location (`ftell(myfile)`) is nonzero, or you can try to check if the file already exists [but that's problematic, because between the check and the actual opening, the file may have been deleted or created]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid race conditions, opening and checking for existence should be done in one system call. In POSIX this can be done with `open` as it will not create the file if the flag `O_CREAT` is not provided.

```c
int fd;
FILE *fp = NULL;
fd = open ("file-name", O_APPEND);
if (fd >= 0) {
  /* successfully opened the file, now get a FILE datastructure */
  fp = fdopen (fd, "a")
}
```

`open` may fail for other reasons too. If you do not want to ignore all of them, you will have to check `errno`.

```c
int fd;
FILE *fp = NULL;
do {
  fd = open ("file-name", O_APPEND);
  /* retry if open was interrupted by a signal */
} while (fd < 0 && errno == EINTR); 
if (fd >= 0) {
  /* successfully opened the file, now get a FILE datastructure */
  fp = fdopen (fd, "a")
} else if (errno != ENOENT) { /* ignore if the file does not exist */
  perror ("open file-name");  /* report any other error */
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the same situation. I wanted to have a data/column header in first raw of my output datafile, even if data is being appended. So only if file doesn't exist, I will print the first line as column headers. I just opened the file in read option ("r"), and checked if it returned NULL. If NULL I will go forward printing the column header, and continue to append data. Is there any problem with this approach?

```
    fp = fopen(file,"r");
    if(!fp)
    {
            fp = fopen(file,"a");
            fprintf(fp,"#col-1\tcol-2\tcol-3\n");
    }
    else
    {
            fclose(fp);
            fp = fopen(file,"a");
    }
    fprintf(fp,"%d,%d,%d\n",val1,val2,val3);
```

Comment: This "stepped" approach works in "casual" situations but contains a "race condition": If another program tries to open or create the file in parallel, it may create it between the point when you check for existence and your code which depends on the file not existing. But the file has been created in the meantime, and the assumption is now invalid, and the dependency violated! This can lead to errors, for example when the file is a lockfile for a resource. Or if the other actor is malicious and writes to the file which you assume is empty -- imagine you write a shell script!

Comment: I don't have anything running in parallel, looking at same file. I guess I am safe in this case, right?

Comment: Yes, that's a safe situation. I just wanted to make that remark to prevent people in other situations from copying the code blindly.