# Execute Tokenize Command

Tags: c

First of all, I'm new to C so pardon me if asking too much.

I have a function that tokenize an input by the user so let's say

```
user input: test -f myFile
```

then after the tokenize function it becomes

```
abc[0] = test
abc[1] = -f
abc[2] = myFile
```

However, at the same time, I also need to use the return value from that input (`test`) statement whether it is FALSE or TRUE (file exist or not exist).

I did **(MY PROBLEM)**

```
if (*abc != '1') {
    printf ("nope.");
}
```

in hope for telling me first whether that file is valid / exist or not, before I call some other function. However, it says warning comparison between pointer and integer.

My original plan is:

```
// ask the user for input

// tokenize the input

if (*abc != '1') { // check the return value from the input
        printf ("nope.");
    }

// call another function
```

Any input why MYPROBLEM doesn't work? How do I execute `test` after I tokenize?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether anything was added to `abc`, you would have to initialize your array to NULs prior to calling tokenize and then afterwards,  `if (**abc == '\0')` would tell you that nothing was tokenized.

However, it's probably better for your tokenize function to return a flag that indicates success or failure in addition to populating your array.

As for executing `test`, you can use the `system()` function or one of the `exec()` functions.