# creat() overwrite my file

Tags: c, linux, filenames, file-permissions

I wrote down a small C code on linux with a `creat` function. I used it couple of times with the same file name and the same `mode` and every time it's overwrites my file with a new time and permission with no `EEXIST` error.

```
 if (creat(name, mode) < 0)
{
    printf("something went wrong with create! %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: If that's not what you want, why are you calling `creat`?!

Comment: I want to create but I want it to check first if this file exists.

Comment: Can you be very, very specific about exactly what you want to do? What do you want to happen if the file already exists? What do you want to happen if the file does not exist? What do you want to happen if the file exists but is a symbolic link?

Answer (score 4):

`EEXIST` is only returned if `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` is used in the flags to `open`. While [`creat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/creat) does imply `O_CREAT`, it does not imply `O_EXCL`, only `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC`.

You should instead use `open`.

Comment: so every time I want to create a file I need to try to open it first? there is no way to check while creating if the file exists to avoid overwrite it?

Comment: @DvirNaim You want to open a file right, creating it if it doesn't not exist and failing if it does exist? Is that correct? If so, you don't need to try to open it "first", all you need to do is try to open it in such a way that the open fails if the file already exists.

Comment: found it..I tought that creat will do the job for me..I was worng...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform

Comment: But `creat()` opens the file too!

Answer (score 3):

> The creat() function is the same as:
>
> ```
> open(path, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, mode);
> ```

You need the flags `O_APPEND` to write at the end of the file

So you should use `open()` `read()` `write()`

**EDIT**

exemple :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_file_exist (char *filename)
{
  struct stat   buffer;   
  return (stat (filename, &buffer) == 0);
}

void open_read_write() {
  int fd;

  if (!is_file_exist("./file"))
    return ;
  // open a file descriptor, if not, create
  fd = open("./file", O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
  // thanks to O_APPEND, write() writes at the end of the file
  write(fd, "hello world\n", 12);
  // close the file descriptor
  close(fd); // important !
}
```

Comment: so every time I want to create a file I need to try to open it first? there is no way to check while creating if the file exists to avoid overwrite it?

Comment: Exactly, but you can create your own function to make the task easily
the `open()` function give you a `file descriptor`, it's needed for reading or writing into a file

Comment: How..? which tools do I need..?

Comment: found it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform