# Regarding saving text file in c programming with similar names

Tags: c, file

I want to save files in c programming and the files names should be like this:

1. it should be game1.txt if game1.txt doesnt exist.
2. it should be game2.txt if game1.txt exists.
3. it should be game3.txt if game2.txt exists.

and so on...
so how should I do that????

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be portable:

- Use a loop and a counter
- `sprintf()` the filename with format-string "game%d.txt"
- `fopen()` the file for reading
- - If this succeeds: close it an continue
- - If it fails: exit from the loop and open the file for writing

Note that there is a race condition: If opening for reading failed, another process could create the file before you open it for writing.

There is a GNU-extension for the `fopen()` mode flags "x", which is for exclusive opening. Using this would eliminate the race condition.

Comment: The `x` flag is part of the `fopen()` function defined in C11 and also part of the `fopen_s()` function documented in Annex K.3.5 of C11.  It might even be available on Windows, therefore, if you use `fopen_s()`.

Answer (score 0):

From this question here, [What's the best way to check if a file exists in C? (cross platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform), the best solution seems to use the `access()` function found in the `unistd.h` header.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const size_t MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 12;
const int MAX_FILENAME_TRIES = 1000;

char *get_next_filename()
{
    char *filename = malloc(MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH);
    FILE *file;
    int found = 0, i = 0;

    do {
        snprintf(filename, "game%d.txt");
        if (access(filename, F_OK) < 0) { //if file does not exist, we've found our name!
            found = 1;
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    } while (! found && i < MAX_FILENAMES_TRIES);
    return filename;
}
```

The code here returns the next available filename as a C string, starting from `game0.txt` up to gameN.txt, where N is the value of MAX_FILENAME_TRIES. Don't forget to `free()` the file name once you've used it.

Comment: If you're going to use POSIX `access()`, it's worth avoiding the race condition with POSIX `open()` and `O_EXCL | O_CREAT` amongst the flags, so it creates the file if it doesn't exist but fails if it does without the TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) vulnerability. You can use `fdopen()` to convert the file descriptor (`int`) into a file stream (`FILE *`). This is like `mkstemp()` — it creates the file and returns the file descriptor. It might be better to have the space for the name passed into the function rather than forcing the use of `malloc()` and `free()`; no leak from your code.