# C on linux How to check if file exists and create new if it does not exist - in symlink tolerant fashion

Tags: c, linux, file, atomic, symlink

I need to write c code on linux that will check if

1) a file exists and

2) if it does not exist then I need to open the file and write into the file.

Being a multi thread / multi process environment, I want to ensure that 1 and two above happen in one atomic operation

I looked at  [What's the best way to check if a file exists in C? (cross platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform) and considered solution suggested by @Dan Lenski. So please dont mark this as duplicate without reading completely . The problem with that is the combination of O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_EXCL flags in an open system call as mentioned in  [open man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open)  does not tolerate symbolic links. Sounds like it has problems with NFS partitions as well

We do use symbolic links in our paths ( Debatable - why but we do end up using ) 
so I want to do something akin Dan's suggested and cited in his code fragment reproduced below but what can tolerate a path that points to a symbolic link

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

fd = open(pathname, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if (fd < 0) {
  /* failure */
  if (errno == EEXIST) {
    /* the file already existed */
    ...
  }
} else {
  /* now you can use the file */
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `O_EXCL`? Is an existing file not usable for you, if not, why?

Comment: [lstat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lstat.html) is what you need, I guess.

Comment: If your intention is not to touch an existing file and just fail in this case, `O_EXCL` is good enough, why should it matter whether the file that's *in the way* is a symlink or not?

Comment: Regarding your edit, you can't open **and** write atomically. If this is important, you'll need e.g. a mutex.

Comment: Another approach would be not to use `O_EXCL` and then check whether the file is non-empty using `fstat()`. But your exact requirements still remain a bit mysterious to me. Will the other threads even touch the file?

Comment: What shall happen if the file already exists? What shall happen if it does not, but you don't have permission to create it?

Comment: @Felix Palmen - Other threads will do the same thing - check if the file exists - if it does not they will create it and start writing to it. If it does exist they will leave it alone assuming its being worked upon already

Comment: @YogeshDevi Then you really should protect it with a mutex. After locking the mutex, you can just open it with `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY`, if necessary check the size with `fstat()` or just truncate it, whatever needs to be done in case there's already data in it.

Comment: I guess so - that I need a mutex

Comment: Does it matter if there is a symlink? (I assume the issue is with a symlink as the final component.) If there is a link, just resolve it, and then open with `O_EXCL` to the path pointed to by the link. Even if someone changes the symlink at the same time, you should get a consistent read on it, a path it actually pointed to.