# create file in c without duplicates

Tags: c, file

I am trying to write a program where i want to create a file using the id given by the user but is the file already exists then i want my program not to overwrite it but show some message like already exists. how can i do that.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct student_info{
    char fName[10],lName[10],depart[10],student_id[10];
    long borrowed_books[5];

};

int main(){
   struct student_info student;
   FILE *fpt;
   printf("enter your id:\n");
   scanf("%s",student.student_id);
   printf("enter your first name:\n");
   scanf("%s",student.fName);
   printf("enter your last name:\n");
   scanf("%s",student.lName);
   printf("enter your department:\n");
   scanf("%s",student.depart);

   fpt=fopen(student.student_id,"w");


fclose(fpt);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c

Comment: recommend checking if the file exists ASAP before continuing on and letting the user enter the remaining information ... that's a waste of time if the info will simply be discarded.

Comment: @yano Yeah.. I hate these websites where they are asking for tons of information only to reject it for some stupid reason after you hit "submit"...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to check if a file exists in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c)