# how to know if fopen creates a new file or opens an existing file?

Tags: fopen

```
FILE *file = NULL;
errno_t err = 0;
err = fopen(&file, "test.txt", "ab+");
```

Now I need to know if test.txt already existed & opened or just newly created.
It's because I have to do something only if it is a newly created but do nothing when it is an existing one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

before your fopen you can check if it exists: answer found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230068/8301539) on StackOverflow